# Adding React Native Package in existig React Native app with typescript throwing error on comipilation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webpack, react-native-web

I am adding web support for in react native app using react native web.
I followed CRA ( create react app ) approach with react native web and react scripts start to build web build for react native.

But during compilation I am getting errors in node modules like :

[image]

[image]

I am unable to understand what is going wrong. Even if I am not using this in my entry component which is just a button. Still it is giving error. any idea?

I tried changing webpack and babel configuration and still getting error.
I attached only 2 screen shots but I am getting errors in multiple node modules. Any idea what approach should I follow